# Java ActiveMQ sending large Object throwing EOFException

Tags: java, activemq-classic, large-object-heap, eofexception

Getting java.io.EOFException while sending a large java object using AciveMQ.

Below is the large object that I am trying to send

```
class TestDataBean implements Serializable
{
private String testName = "TestName";
private String testDesc = "testDesc";

private String bigData = getBigString();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return testName +" : "+testDesc+" : "+bigData.length();
}


private static String getBigString() 
{
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0;i<1000; i++)
    {
        stringBuffer.append("tsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

Below is the stackTrace.

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readLongUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)Recieved MSG : 0 : null

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at poc_publisher_subsciber.common.CommonUtil.getObject(CommonUtil.java:18)
at blob_messages.bsr_clients.GenesisMessageListener.onMessage(GenesisMessageListener.java:30)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1298)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Producer showing that its sending a proper object. But on consumer side it throws above exception.

I have also tried below configurations with ActiveMQConnectionFactory

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        factory.setProducerWindowSize(1024000000);
        factory.setSendTimeout(600000);
```

Please suggest me some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception is occurring on the client side while receiving the object? Can we see that code if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was my mistake. Let me explain u what I was doing. - I was sending the message as StreamMessage - And reading this one in a byte array The size of data I was sending was about 70K bytes and As a SILLY MISTAKE the array I had was jus 10K capacity. n so I was getting this EOFException. Sorry I take ur time. And posting this hoping that no one else would be doing similar mistake :) Thanks.